# Generic function in interface to return concrete implementation

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-generics

To an interface, I want to add a function that returns an object of the concrete implementation.

So with the interface:

```
interface Content {
        fun <???> cloneMe(): ?
}
```

and the classes

```
class Music: Content
class Video: Content
```

the function `cloneMe()` of the `Music` class should return a `Music` object and the the  function `cloneMe()` of the `Video` class should return a `Video` object.

The closest I've come is:

```
interface Content {
    fun <T: Content> cloneMe(): T
}

class Music : Content {
    override fun <T : Content> cloneMe(): T {
        return Music() as T
    }
}
```

then I can do

```
val music: Music = Music().cloneMe<Music>()
```

The problem here is that I have to do an unchecked cast, which 'allows me' (i.e. will compile) to do

```
class Music : Content {
        override fun <T : Content> cloneMe(): T {
            return Video() as T
        }
}
```

which is problematic.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically this is done by parameterizing the `Content` interface as well, as follows:

```
interface Content<T : Content<T>> {
    fun cloneMe(): T
}
```

And the implementation:

```
class Music : Content<Music> {
    override fun cloneMe(): Music {
        return Music()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to achieve is not necessary related to any Generics. Instead you could just use the type directly and implement a more detailed override.

```
interface Content {
    fun cloneMe(): Content
}

class Music : Content {
    override fun cloneMe() = Music()
}
```

Comment: This offloads the responsibility for downcasting onto the caller, the avoidance of which it seems to me is the implied intent of the original question.

Comment: @TimKeating how so? The return type of `Music.cloneMe()` is actually `Music`. The only advantage of having Generics here is the checking of the proper return type if the class is defined properly.

Comment: Not true. The return type of `cloneMe()` is `Content`, regardless of the fact that you call it from a `Music` and it returns a `Music` instance. You can't, for example, call a hypothetical `setVolume()` method on your cloned object without explicitly casting it to a `Music`. You can easily verify this in the REPL.

Comment: @TimKeating it depends on the type of your variable. If you call `cloneMe()` on a `Content` instance, you'll only get a `Content` returned. The same holds true for `Content<*>`. If you have a `Content<Music>` or `Music` variable, you'll get a `Music` returned. For both cases you need to know about the `Music` definition. Using the generic supertype won't yield anything.

Comment: This won't work if you're using the `Content` interface as a generic type parameter in other functions.